# Disable touchpad while typing on external keyboard

Tags: linux, gnome

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad disable-while-typing true
```

the above tweak disables my laptop's internal keyboard while typing. But this doesn't work same for the external keyboard. Is there anything I can do? I also tried tweaking the libinput config. But nothing seems to work for the external keyboard.